# sending email contact form c# asp.net visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, visual-studio-2012

I'am working on this fro a few days now and although it won't give me an error it also doesn't send the emails.(I don't receive any).
(The msg that the email is send will display on my contact form...)

I have created a contact form in asp.net c# -it is running on my local host,but I want to send an email to my gmail or outlook account.

The question is... what is wrong with my code? Any suggestions?

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Here is the code:

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid) //if all boxes are filled in...
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txtbxEmailAddress.Text); //sender email address 
                mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
                mailMessage.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");    //receiver email address               
                mailMessage.Body = txtRequest.Text;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Subject = " Contact Us";

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblMailmsg.Text = String.Format("Error sending email");
            }

            lblMailmsg.Text = String.Format("Your Message has been sent. We will be in contact with you as soon as possible."); //msg show when mail is sent

            //clear contact form
            txtbxfname.Text = "";
            txtbxLName.Text = "";
            txtbxEmailAddress.Text = "";
            txtRequest.Text = "";
        }
        }
}       



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue I see what your code is this line.

```
mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
```

This will break SPF and also cause DMARC to fail and you will never get the message from some people.

You can read more about that here: ["DMARC - Contact Form Nightmare"](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

The suggested workaround will be to do:

```
mailMessage.From = "myemail@gmail.com"
mailMessage.Subject = " Contact Us" + fromAddress;
```

This way - you avoid the issue outline in the article.

Comment: YES! Thank you soo much :) I changed it to: 
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
mailMessage.Subject = " Contact Us" + fromAddress; 
And I receive the email in my gmail. :)

Problem now is that when I recieve the email in gmail it is from me, not from the emailaddress that was filled in by the user in the contact form. 
How do I change that? Thank you very much as I know now where the problem is ...:)

Comment: You can't change that, that's the whole issue - It's going to be a little more work on your part, to respond to the customer. But at least you'll get the emails from the customer to respond to.

Comment: OK Thank You.I was hoping to change that as well,shame that can't be done :( But you are right, at least i am receiving the emails! :) Thanks again!